# how can I filter a huge log file?

Tags: text-processing

i have data

```
15:29:05:493582: Impact Cost :Current[0.20] Required[5.00] Bid[price:3195 qty:450] Ask[price:3215 qty:600].
15:29:05:480193: Impact Cost :Current[0.15] Required[5.00] Bid[price:3195 qty:450] Ask[price:3210 qty:75].
15:29:05:462943: Impact Cost :Current[0.20] Required[5.00] Bid[price:3195 qty:450] Ask[price:3215 qty:600].
15:29:05:462886: Impact Cost :Current[0.20] Required[5.00] Bid[price:3195 qty:450] Ask[price:3215 qty:600].
15:29:05:462789: Impact Cost :Current[0.20] Required[5.00] Bid[price:3195 qty:450] Ask[price:3215 qty:600].
15:29:05:447389: Impact Cost :Current[0.15] Required[5.00] Bid[price:3195 qty:450] Ask[price:3210 qty:75].
15:29:05:446545: Impact Cost :Current[0.20] Required[5.00] Bid[price:3195 qty:450] Ask[price:3215 qty:600].
15:29:05:446381: Impact Cost :Current[0.20] Required[5.00] Bid[price:3195 qty:525] Ask[price:3215 qty:600].
15:29:05:409039: Impact Cost :Current[0.20] Required[5.00] Bid[price:3195 qty:75] Ask[price:3215 qty:600].
15:29:05:409019: Impact Cost :Current[0.20] Required[5.00] Bid[price:3195 qty:75] Ask[price:3215 qty:600].
```

i want to output as

```
Bid[price:3195 qty:450] Ask[price:3215 qty:600].
Bid[price:3195 qty:450] Ask[price:3210 qty:75].
Bid[price:3195 qty:450] Ask[price:3215 qty:600].
Bid[price:3195 qty:450] Ask[price:3215 qty:600].
Bid[price:3195 qty:450] Ask[price:3215 qty:600].
Bid[price:3195 qty:450] Ask[price:3210 qty:75].
Bid[price:3195 qty:450] Ask[price:3215 qty:600].
Bid[price:3195 qty:525] Ask[price:3215 qty:600].
Bid[price:3195 qty:75] Ask[price:3215 qty:600].
Bid[price:3195 qty:75] Ask[price:3215 qty:600].
```

please tell me how to extract it from .txt file using terminal.

Comment: Are the rows always in this format, or may some rows contain different fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a really simple one. If you only want everything starting with the word "Bid" through the end of the line, you can use just:

`grep -o 'Bid.*' yourfile.txt`

Answer (score 5):

A solution that doesn't require a regular expression engine:

```
$ cut -d ' ' -f 6- logfile
```

The `cut` utility will in this case give you all columns from column six onwards. It will treat each space on every line as a column delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{ print $6$7$8$9 }' logfile
```